# Convert a dictionary to DataFrame with specified column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is `dict['TimeStamp'] = [value1,value2,value3]`
the dict has many times stamps and each time stamp has 3 values for example
I want to make panda dataframe of all values of dictionary  of column1, 2, 3

```
dict['timestamp1'] = [1,2,3]
dict['timestamp2'] = [4,5,6]
```

I wanna make a panda frame of  pd [timestamp] = dict.keys
and rename all the values of columns as

```
pd['firstcolumn'] = [1,4,..etc]
pd['secondcolumn'] = [2,5,..etc]
pd['thirdcolumn'] = [3,6,..etc]
```

is that possible ?

Comment: Can you get your desired result by passing in the dictionary as `pd.DataFrame(dict)`, then transpose it with `df=df.T`?

Comment: @G.Anderson I wanna name the columns with names to output them in an excel file

Comment: `df.columns = ['firstcolumn','secondcolumn','thirdcolumn']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in one line by unpacking the dictionary and labeling your columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[*dict.values()], columns=['firstcolumn','secondcolumn', 'thirdcolumn'])
```

Edit: You can add the timestamps in their own column, but the unpacking process is a little more complicated:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[[item[0], *(item[1:][0])] for item in dict.items()], columns=['TimeStamp', 'firstcolumn','secondcolumn', 'thirdcolumn'])
```

Comment: I need to add timestamp1, timestamp2, in the same df with the header TimeStamp – chris burgees

Comment: Thanks so much!. Is it possible to sort pandaframe by TimeStamp ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at [sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below code that does the same:

```
dict = {'timestamp1' : [1,2,3], 'timestamp2':[3,4,5], 'timestamp3' : [6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.T
```

Output:

```
           0    1   2
timestamp1  1   2   3
timestamp2  3   4   5
timestamp3  6   7   8
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the dict values as your data and then pass it to the `DataFrame` constructor along with a corresponding list of the column names you want.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'timestamp1': [1,2,3], 'timestamp2': [4,5,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), columns=['first_col', 'second_col', 'third_col'])

print(df)
#    first_col  second_col  third_col
# 0          1           2          3
# 1          4           5          6
```

Per the additional question in your comment, you could include the dict keys in their own column by adding the corresponding key to each list of values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[k, *v] for k, v in d.items()], columns=['Timestamp', 'first_col', 'second_col', 'third_col'])

print(df)
#     Timestamp  first_col  second_col  third_col
# 0  timestamp1          1           2          3
# 1  timestamp2          4           5          6
```

Or with dict keys as index named "Timestamp".

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['first_col', 'second_col', 'third_col'])
df.index.names = ['Timestamp']

print(df)
#             first_col  second_col  third_col
# Timestamp                                   
# timestamp1          1           2          3
# timestamp2          4           5          6
```

Comment: I need to add timestamp1, timestamp2, in the same df with the header TimeStamp

Comment: can I name timestamp column as TimeStamp ?

Answer (score -1):

Pandas does this out of the box. Just pass the dictionary to `pd.DataFrame`

```
p = {}
p['firstcolumn'] = [1,4]
p['secondcolumn'] = [2,5]
p['thirdcolumn'] = [3,6]
df = pd.DataFrame(p)
```

You also mentioned wanting to push to excel, which is easy with Pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(p)
df.columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"]
df.to_excel("file.xlsx")
```

Edit: this solution shows you the steps one-by-one, but @ppinchuk's answer does your original request in one line, so I think it's better.